# How can I use the Print Dialog

Tags: c#, printing

If you go in Visual Studio 2005 to the following (or just do ctrl+p):
File ==> Print..

You get a print dialog screen.  I want the same in my program, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dialog box is a so-called *common dialog*, a built-in Windows dialog that can be used by multiple applications.

To use this dialog box in your C# application, you can use the `PrintDialog` class. The following MSDN pages contains descriptions as well as some sample code:

- WinForms: [System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx)
- WPF: [System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx) (thanks to [Bartosz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051623/how-can-i-use-the-print-dialog/8051660#8051660))

Answer (score 2):

If you use WPF, you may use `PrintDialog`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx

if you're into WinForms you may use...`PrintDialog`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For the CTRL+P shortcut:
Add a toolbar (I think it was called ToolStrip) to your form, put an entry in it to wich you assign the shortcut CTRL+P from the properties panel.
For the PrintDialog:
Add a PrintDialog control to your form and set the Document property to the document that should be printed. Go into the code for the click event of your print entry in the toolbar. Add the code `PrintDialog.ShowDialog();` to it, check if the Print button was clicked, and if so, print it using `DocumentToPrint.Print();`.
Here's an example:

```
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, 
        System.EventArgs e)
    {

        // Allow the user to choose the page range he or she would
        // like to print.
        PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;

        // Show the help button.
        PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = true;

        // Set the Document property to the PrintDocument for 
        // which the PrintPage Event has been handled. To display the
        // dialog, either this property or the PrinterSettings property 
        // must be set 
        PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint;

        DialogResult result = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // If the result is OK then print the document.
        if (result==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            docToPrint.Print();
        }

    }
```

Example source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.document.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the fleshed-out example.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a standard print dialog with this:

```
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.ShowDialog();
```

... but printing has to be done by yourself ... ;-)

**Edit**: For all those who still use VisualStudio2005:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Oh come on - do the Math and change it to `PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog()` yourself... *rolleyes*

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: No, Thorsten, I will not do that. In every case, where it is clear which type a variable has, I will write a `var`. I am a "man of conviction" in that case. :-)

Comment: @Fischermaen: I was talking to Remco ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: oops, missed that. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Umm, you can use the cleverly named [PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx) class....

Answer (score 0):

If your using WinForms to build your UI, then you can use the native PrintDialog control (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx)). So far as I know, that should appear in the Toolbox in the designer mode of a WinForms control.